# Существование объекта до завершения конструктора в Java

Tags: многопоточность, java

Не могу понять пример из книги про многопоточность в Java. Каким образом может получиться n!=n? По идее, пока конструктор не выполнится, объект не будет существовать:

```
public Holder holder;
public void initialize() {
    holder = new Holder(42);
}

public class Holder {
    private int n;

    public Holder(int n) { 
        this.n = n; 
    }

    public void assertSanity() {
        if (n != n)
            throw new AssertionError("This is false.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не знаю, что точно они хотели этим показать. Этот пример неполный или к нему, вероятно, были какие-то комментарии. Главное, что в нём непонятно, так это откуда и как вызывается assertSanity? И почему вы связали свои рассуждения с конструктором?

Но прямо в таком виде, как здесь написано, такое может быть только в одном случае: на SMP-архитектурах с разделёнными контроллерами памяти или кешами.. тогда может такое быть, что если n слева берётся на одном процессоре, а потому происходит переключение на другой процессор и n справа берётся на другом.. и тогда значения могут не совпасть из-за рассинхронизации памяти. Но эта ситуация по идее тоже маловероятно.. по идее ОС должна при переключении синхронизовать кэши, чтобы недопустить такого краха.

Другой вариант может иметься в виду, что в то время как мы вызываем этот метод, кто-то может изменить снаружи n и тогда проверка не сойдётся, но в этом примере не предусмотрено способа изменения n ниоткуда. Стало быть, пример в любом случае неполный и выдран откуда-то из контекста.

Про конструктор: тут вы не совсем правы: во время выполнения конструктора объект уже существует.. вы можете легко в этом убедиться передав указатель this куда-нибудь.. и вы обнаружите, что снаружи этот объект будет выглядеть вполне существующим.

Comment: Предполагается, что assertSanity вызывается из другого потока. Похоже, ваше первое предположение - единственно верная разгадка. n снаружи менять нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Это пример из книги "Java Concurrency in Practice", глава 3.5. Автор объясняет возможность такого поведения особенностью модели памяти Java: изменения объектов в одном потоке не сразу (если вообще) получают лругие потоки. Это более ясно, на мой взгляд, демонстрируется в главе "3.1.1. Stale data" немного ранее в этой же книге. Конретно в этом случае "a thread may see a stale value the first time it reads a field and then a more up-to-date value the next time".

На счет "объект не будет существовать" уже объяснил cy6erGn0m. Можно добавить, кроме того, что до присвоения `n` значения из аргумента конструктора, у него будет значение `0` по умолчанию - stale value в этом случае.

Comment: Да, это действительно Java Concurrency

Comment: Чёрт.. я читал эту книгу слишком давно, чтобы вспомнить этот пример.. а ведь я читал её дважды.. эх.. время летит..

Answer (score 0):

Если мне не изменяет память это проверка на Infinity (тобишь переполнение)